# Nested Loops and Timeout

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a large nested loop (as deep as 6 layers) that generates a decision tree. However, this is a fairly time critical program, I need to abort the generation when the time is up.

I understand that it's possible for each loop to check with the timer, but decreases the efficiency. I was thinking of using a monitor thread or similar mechanism, I want to know if there is an efficient way to set a timeout for the entire loop and break (possibly using "goto" clause)?

Or should I just cut the nested loop into nested threads?

Comment: Have you tried timing a version that checks the timeout and one that doesn't?

Comment: Did you actually make any attempt to profile your code with the timer check? Did it pass 1% of work time?

Answer (score 2):

Just *how* inefficient is it to check the `System.currentTimeMillis()` clock value ? I strongly suspect it's negligible and that might well be your simplest and most efficient option.

Comment: You can do literally millions of them per second on a modern JVM/hardwre.  I did a test.

Comment: I have about 20 loops, is checking for `System.currentTimeMillis()`  in every `for` or `while` loop a good practice? I can definitely do that, I but was just wondering if there would be a more efficient/intuitive way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can test checking a timer on your inner-most loop and if that is too slow move it to your `Level 5`, and if that is too slow your `Level 4`...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop the entire generation process if it did not finish with certain time limit, you can put all your loops in a thread, and allow the thread to run for specific time then terminate if it did not finish. Here is how I would do this:

```
Thread generationThread = new Thread(){

    public void run(){
        // All your loops

        // You can check for isInterrupted and simply return to terminate the process
        if(isInterrupted()){
          return;
        }
    }
}
generationThread.start();
generationThread.join(MAX_TIME); // how long in ms this process is allowed to run
// Terminate the thread if it did not finish
if(generationThread.isAlive()){
   generationThread.interrupt();
}
```

This code for *illustration only*, change it as needed.